# Get linux environment var into php

Tags: php, bash

I'm not able to get the value of `MY_SYSVAR` in php. While I can get the value from command line ...

```
~# /usr/bin/printenv
[...]
MY_SYSVAR=SYSVAR
[...]
```

... these commands give no results:

```
<?php
echo getenv('MY_SYSVAR');
echo $_SERVER['MY_SYSVAR'];
echo $_ENV['MY_SYSVAR'];
?>
```

Comment: I'd hope that it would be `export MY_SYSVAR=SYSVAR` in your bash script rather than just `MY_SYSVAR=SYSVAR`

Comment: MY_SYSVAR coming from printenv, so it must be already exported, do you?

Comment: Are you sure? I could be wrong, but I've always been under the impression that env vars had to be explicitly exported

Comment: Ah, ok. It can be. I'll check for this. Thank you